# PHP order submission total calculate

Tags: php

I made an order form using PHP that makes subtotals for each item ordered. How can I make a function/code to display the total for the order in the bottom of the page. I tried to read on PHP.net but couldn't figure it out.

Here is a sample of my code:

```html
$bread = $_POST["bread"];
$cheese = $_POST["cheese"];
$eggs = $_POST["eggs"];

$priceBread = 5;
$priceCheese = 5;
$priceEggs = 3.6;

function subtotal($incomingQuantity, $incomingPrice){
  return $incomingQuantity * $incomingPrice;
}

<div id="breadSubtotal">$<?php echo subtotal($bread, $priceBread); ?>
<div id="cheeseSubtotal">$<?php echo subtotal($cheese, $priceCheese); ?></div>
<div id="eggsSubtotal">$<?php echo subtotal($eggs, $priceEggs); ?></div>
```

I want the total from the subtotals of all the items

Comment: Do you mean the order for the today price for `priceBread`, `priceCheese` and `priceEggs`?

Comment: You want the sum of sub total. Are they menu item is static?

Comment: @Ranjith Yes it's, I want the total of the subtotals that appear in the div when the 'customer' submit the form

Comment: @RaffyCortez My code is fine, I want an addon which is a function that totals the order which means (quantityBread * priceBread) + (quantityEggs * priceEggs) + (quanitityCheese * priceCheese)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
$total = 0;

function subtotal($incomingQuantity, $incomingPrice){
  global $total;
  $sub = $incomingQuantity * $incomingPrice;
  $total += $sub;
  return $sub;
}
```

then in the HTML

```
<div id="total">$<?php echo $total; ?></div>
```

also, dont forget to make safe your incoming $_POST vars with something like

```
$bread = htmlspecialchars($_POST["bread"]);
```

Comment: Man I appreciate that, it actually worked perfectly! Now I'll figure out a way to make a total quantity!!

Comment: youre welcome. there are some good answers here, but sometimes just a simple global var is the answer

Comment: You're right, this is the first time I use a global variable. I am a super rookie in PHP

Answer (score 0):

> I want the total from the subtotals of all the items

Its really simple to calculate.  Try like this

```
$bread = 2;
$cheese = 3;
$eggs = 4;

$priceBread = 5;
$priceCheese = 5;
$priceEggs = 3.6;
$total = 0;
function subtotal($incomingQuantity, $incomingPrice){
  return $incomingQuantity * $incomingPrice;
}

$total += subtotal($bread, $priceBread) ;
$total += subtotal($bread, $priceBread);
$total += subtotal($cheese, $priceCheese);
echo "order total : " + $total;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's so helpful

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong, you want to calculate the number of each item with the price of the items. So based on that this is how I would do it.

```
public function getTotal()
{
    $total = 0;
    $subTotal = func_get_args();
    for($a = 0; $a < sizeof($subTotal); $a++)
    {
        $total += $subTotal[$a];
    }

    return $total;
 }
```

Test the function

```
getTotal(subtotal($bread, $priceBread), subtotal($cheese, $priceCheese), subtotal($eggs, $priceEggs));
```

Comment: This one is a super simple and clear way to do it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it, gives you more flexibility

```
<?php
$bread = $_POST["bread"];
$cheese = $_POST["cheese"];
$eggs = $_POST["eggs"];

//prices
$prices = array('bread'=>5,'cheese'=>5,'eggs'=>3.6);

function calculateOrderTotals($items, $prices){

    //result
    $result = array('total'=>0, 'subTotal'=>array());

    //total
    $total = 0;

    //calculate subtotal and total
    foreach ($items as $item => $nPurchased){
        $subTotal = $nPurchased* $prices[$item];
        $result['subTotal'][$item] = $subTotal; 
        $total += $subTotal;
    }

    //set total
    $result['total'] = $total;

    //return
    return $result;
}

//call function to calculate    
$totals = calculateOrderTotals(array('bread'=>$bread,'cheese'=>$cheese,'eggs'=>$eggs), $prices);

?>

<div id="breadSubtotal"><?php echo $totals['subTotal']['bread'];?>
<div id="cheeseSubtotal"><?php echo $totals['subTotal']['cheese']; ?></div>
<div id="eggsSubtotal"><?php echo $totals['subTotal']['eggs']; ?></div>
<div id="total"><?php echo $totals['total']; ?></div>
```